# current HTML menu item

Tags: php, html, menu, superfish

I'm working with a template that had duplicate menus defined in each document, with the exception of `<li class="current">` to highlight the menu item of the page you are currently on. I replaced the menu structure with

```
<?php 
include("menu_test.html"); 
?>
```

so I wouldn't have to maintain 7 menus. How can I duplicate the selected menu item per page?

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me, however if you try to include a static file in a dynamic manner this likely won't work. Have you considered to make your menu dynamic based on the menu-points?

Answer (score 0):

- Set global variable that will hold current menu item identifier
- Upon building the menu check which menu is current based on that global variable